# SSIS multiple table loads

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am learning SSIS for the first time. I am trying to load multiple tables from my staging database to multiple tables in the data warehouse. My staging database is nothing but a database with all the tables from all my source databases copied to it. I found that each data flow task only allows to connect one source table to one destination table. Do I have to use as many data flow tasks as the number of tables I have in my source database? Is there a simple and more efficient way to do this?

From my understanding, I would need an empty database with empty Dim and Fact tables created in SQL Server which would act as destination data warehouse and receive the data from the staging database. Therefore I have already created this empty data warehouse. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no convention that you need to have only 1 source and 1 destination in a  DFT (Data Flow Task).

You can have multiple source and destination components inside a DFT. However, you may run out of memory if you have too many source to destination components in a single DFT. In the pre-execute phase SSIS has to decide the memory to allocate for individual S2D components, and if the memory consumption is too high then server may not able to grant enough memory for all the components. This may result in *long waiting*.

However there is a property called `EngineThreads` for DFT which defines how many threads the data flow engine can create and run in parallel. According to MSDN:

> To understand how this property works, consider the sample package with three
>   Data Flow tasks. Each of Data Flow task contains ten source-to-destination
>   execution trees. If you set EngineThreads to 10 on each Data Flow task,
>   all 30 execution trees can potentially run simultaneously.However, the general
>   rule is not to run more threads in parallel than the number of available
>   processors. Running more threads than the number of available processors
>   can hinder performance because of the frequent context-switching between threads.

So it's better to create individual Data Flow Task and perform the operation.

Note: If you are getting data from multiple sources, then you can do it in a single data flow task.

Comment: So if i have only 7 sql tables i could use the same DFT for all 7 S2D threads? is there any other way to do this rather than having 7 individual threads for 7 tables?

Comment: I don't think you have read my answer properly . IF you have `2 many S2D compoenents` then chances are that SSIS may not be able to run all the compoenents parallely and few of the S2D may hang `forever` .It's better to have individual DFT for each `S2D` . But then again you need to test

Comment: Thanks. I thought there would be some other efficient way rather than having one DFT per S2D. Since MSDN says components would hang I will do it one by one then.

Comment: When I tried this method I am getting some conversion error for the input component. I am not sure why do you have any ides?Thnks

Comment: @Gayu : Try to map the columns correctly or post as a new question by elaborating the query and error for the problem you faced